# Camera.Parameters.setZoom() is inconsistent across devices, in some device it zooms more

Tags: android, android-camera, zooming, camera-calibration

I am making a custom camera app, and I am using the Android Camera API for that. I know this API is deprecated now and it is recommended to use the Camera2 API.
But I have to only preview the camera with some zoom.

Below is the code for setting the zoom

```
Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
 parameters.setZoom(30);
  parameters.setPreviewFpsRange(
                previewFpsRange[Camera.Parameters.PREVIEW_FPS_MIN_INDEX],
                previewFpsRange[Camera.Parameters.PREVIEW_FPS_MAX_INDEX]);
  parameters.setPreviewFormat(IMAGE_FORMAT);
 camera.setParameters(parameters);
```

Now, the problem is that the camera zoom is not equal across devices, some devices zoom in to a good amount whereas some devices zoom very much.

I am not able to find any explanation over the internet regarding the same.

I need the same zoom level across all the Android devices irrespective of the camera quality and MP.

Answer (score 1):

The legal Value of Camera.Parameters.setZoom() goes from 0 to Camera.Parameters.getMaxZoom() as you can read in the [Documentation of setZoom()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters#setZoom(int))

What you have to do is to normalize the Zoom factor over all devices, which can be done with the following method:

```
 private setZoom(float zoom) {//to me, here zoom 0 to 1 
 try {
    if (isCameraOpened() && mCameraParameters.isZoomSupported()) {
        int maxZoom = mCameraParameters.getMaxZoom();
        int scaledValue = (int) (zoom * maxZoom);
        mCameraParameters.setZoom(scaledValue);
        mZoom = zoom;
        mCamera.setParameters(mCameraParameters);
    }
  } catch (Exception | Error throwable) {
    Log.e(TAG, Objects.requireNonNull(throwable.getMessage()));
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the OP. getMaxZoom() changes based on device and is calibrated to their supported zoom values. Hence, a percentage of that will differ based on device.
Having said that, I am yet to find the answer myself.